# Files in VSCode still appear deleted after merging a pull request from another branch to main

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request, git-clone

I have a git repository in which I create a branch for each new feature I add to the app. The latest branch was 6 commits ahead `main` and I merged it.

Some new files were created in the new branch that were not in `main` so I figured that after merging they will also appear in VSCode after changing the branch. But they did not.

The new files appeared inside the repository in the `main` branch, but when I switched to `main` in VSCode it was 6 commits behind.

I cloned the repo, but that does not update my code, it only creates a new up-to-date folder.

I know that I can clone the project in another folder, but I want to know if there is any way that I could update my code after merging into `main`. Thanks.